# How does Mocha do DOM testing without phantomjs

Tags: node.js, tdd, phantomjs, mocha.js

I seem to be able to do DOM tests with Mocha.

I had assumed I needed a headless browser like PhantomJS.

What's the benefit of using PhantomJS with Mocha then? (I'm using Yeoman.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need a headless browser to do DOM tests with Mocha. A package like jsdom provides a good deal of what's needed to do DOM testing without having to use a browser, headless or not. For instance, We've used it for [testing code](https://github.com/mangalam-research/wed/blob/develop/test/lib/wed/dloc_test.js) that walks a DOM tree.

However, Mocha itself does not provide support for DOM in Node.js. Something else has to provide this support. If you follow some of the tutorials out on the net, you may end up installing support for DOM without realizing it. For instance, a tutorial that shows how to test jQuery code in Node.js using Mocha will tell you to do `npm install jquery`, which also installs jsdom.

You'd have to use something like PhantomJS if other solutions don't provide the functionality you need. For instace jsdom does not provide the `MutationObserver` interface. (There's a configuration setting named `MutationEvents` but turning it on does not provide `MutationObserver`.) So if you need to test code that depends on `MutationObserver` you have to use something else, like PhantomJS.

Comment: What will you do when you want to cross browser test your code? Is jsdom enough? @Louis

Comment: @InancGumus For cross-browser compatibility, nothing replaces testing on actual browsers. For instance, IE does not accept [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) with an `undefined` value for the reference element. It has to be `null`. Testing only with jsdom won't reveal this.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I think the same . I wanted everyone aware about it. Do you know that is there a possible way of abstracting dom; if I want to use jsdom for DOM I can use it; Or if I want to use underlying real DOM I can also use it. Do you know is there an abstraction solution for this? @Louis